# How to save large record csv to database in spring

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I using spring boot and using postgresSql. Now i using csv upload 7000 row into db same time. When i upload it cannot save my db. I waiting one hour but no data save to db. When i upload 1000 record i save success. I know very large data save to db in same time. I try using batch_size and set it to 50. But my entity using with primary key autoincrement by indentify  then i can't using batch_size. When i using batch_size, batch_size not work. I don't know how to save 7000 record into postgresSql. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide some information on your persistence layer. A code snippet would help too.

Comment: It's better to show us your code. Your information is not enough.